# Find and replace an obfuscated word or phrase in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a singe word or n-word phrase within a string and then replace it with asterisks. The challenge is I want to do this even when the word or n-word phrase is obfuscated by certain characters.

Assume the following. `REPLACE_CHAR` is the character I want to use to replace the word or n-word phrase. `ILLEGAL_CHAR` are the characters I want to ignore. I also want this to ignore case.

```py
REPLACE_CHAR = "*"
ILLEGAL_CHAR = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

#### Example one

Here, I want to replace "dolor" with asterisks. In the string, you can see that "dolor" exists but it's obfuscated with random symbols and capitalization.

```py
string = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR sit amet"
find = "dolor"
```

The idea result would be `"Lorem ipsum ***** sit amet"` where the number of asterisk match the length of the found word.

### Example two

Here, I want to replace "dolor sit" with asterisks while keeping spaces. In the string, you can see that "dolor sit" exists but it's obfuscated with random symbols and capitalization.

```py
string = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR s%)i!T~ amet"
find = "dolor sit"
```

The idea result would be `"Lorem ipsum ***** *** amet"` where the number of asterisk match the length of the found word.

---

### Update #1

This solution builds off of @Ajax1234 response.

Rather than use `re.sub` to remove `ILLEGAL_CHAR`, we use `translate` and build the table outside the function. This has a slight performance boost.

```py
import re

REPLACE_CHAR = "*"
ILLEGAL_CHAR = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

trans = str.maketrans("", "", ILLEGAL_CHAR)
text = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR sit amet"
token = "dolor sit"

def replace(data, token):
    data = data.translate(trans)
    return re.sub(token, lambda x:' '.join('*'*len(i) for i in x.group().split(' ')), data, flags=re.I)

print(replace(text, token))
```

Comment: Dont know a way to do it using `regex` but you can find matching pattern using `Longest common sub sequence.`

Comment: What behavior do you want when there are obfuscating characters outside of the word or phrase you are interested in? For example if the string were `string = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR s%)i!T~ amet ()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

ignore_chars = "!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"

string = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR s%)i!T~ amet"

clean_string = "".join(char for char in string if char not in ignore_chars)

bad_words = ["dolor", "sit"]

for bad_word in bad_words:
    pattern = f"\\b{bad_word}\\b"
    replace = "*" * len(bad_word)
    clean_string = re.sub(pattern, replace, clean_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(clean_string)
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum ***** *** amet
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to keep spaces when using n-word phrases. For instance, use `["dolor sit"]` for `bad_words`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` to remove the illegal characters, then apply another `re.sub` with `re.I`:

```
import re
def replace(word, target):
   w = re.sub('[\!"#\$%\&\'\(\)\*\+,\-\./:;\<\=\>\?@\[\]\^_`\{\|\}~]+', '', word)
   return re.sub(target, lambda x:' '.join('*'*len(i) for i in x.group().split(' ')), w, flags=re.I)
```

---

```
string = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR sit amet"
find = "dolor"
r = replace(string, find)
```

Output:

```
'Lorem ipsum ***** sit amet'
```

---

```
string = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR s%)i!T~ amet"
find = "dolor sit"
r = replace(string, find)
```

Output:

```
'Lorem ipsum ***** *** amet'
```

Comment: Using translate (creating the translation table outside the function) improves performance. Testing against 1 million iterations, translate was ~1 second faster.

Comment: @mondoshawan That is good to know. Can you post your solution with `translate`?

Answer (score 1):

With `re.sub` at your disposal, un- and re-obfuscating words is not too tough to do! There's a lot of good answers here already; this one was designed to be easy-to-edit, especially if you plan to get input from users or some other external source.

```py
#we'll be using regex to solve this problem
import re


#establish some constants - these can be changed later, or even read as user input
REPLACE_CHAR = "*"
ILLEGAL_CHAR = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'


#your search string - this can be read as user input
search = "Lorem ipsum %@do^l&oR sit amet"

#this regex will remove the illegal characters - specifically, it substitutes an empty 
#character ('') in place of any illegal character we find. 
#note that since the brackets are included here, the user can directly input illegal 
#symbols themselves without worrying about formatting
strip = re.sub('['+ILLEGAL_CHAR+']', '', search)


#the string to obfuscate - this can also be read as user input
find = "ipsum dolor sit"

#this splits the words on spaces, so there's spaces between tee asterisks
find_words = find.split(' ')


#now we'll check each find_word - we'll look for it in the string, and if we find it,
#we'll replace it with asterisks of the same length as the original word. 
#(we'll use a ranged for loop to go over the words)
for f_word in find_words:

  #check each f_word to see if it appears in the string. note "flags=re.I" - this 
  #tells our regex to use case-insensitive matching
  if(re.search(f_word, strip, flags=re.I)):

    #we found a word! check the length of the word, then substitute an equal number of
    #REPLACE_CHARs
    strip = re.sub(f_word, (REPLACE_CHAR * len(f_word)), strip, flags=re.I)

#ta-daa!
print(strip)
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/AwesomeAdventurousFunnel)